# Nativscript and XSS

Tags: xss

Does a mobile application written with Nativescript, which utilizes a cross-platform Javascript runtime, have the same XSS vulnerability as a website?

Comment: XSS implies something coming from another site; if the html/js is all local, that doesn't apply.

Comment: Actually I am mostly concerned over an unescaped user input to break the context of the xml during binding and thus inject some code like "tap=...". Is that possible with Nativescript as it is with the browser? What kind of measures keep it from happening? There is also the eval() possibility too.